# How to uninstall an older django version from virtual environment?

Tags: django, pip, conda

I have created a virtual environment on my computer using conda .

```
conda create --name myDjangoEnv django
```

It installed django version 2.0.5
Then when I upgraded to a new django version(2.1) in the same environment , both of the django versions were showing up . I also tried uninstalling the old version using the pip command

```
pip uninstall django==2.0.5
```

It is pointing to the new installation saying django 2.1 will be unistalled . How to remove the old version and use the new one ?

Comment: How about you uninstall all versions of django installed and installing the right version again ?

Comment: Have you activated the environment with `conda activate myDjangoEnv` ?